# How to save save data with NSS string with more than one box

Tags: ios5, nsstring, uitextfield, xcode4.3

Im saving data and reloading using the follwing code.

```
- (IBAction)savefirstline:(id)sender {
NSString *savecontents = firstlineofadsress.text; 
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savecontents forKey:@"savecontents2"];
[defaults synchronize];



- (IBAction)loadfirstline:(id)sender {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"savecontents2"];
[firstlineofadsress setText:loadstring];
```

My question is how do i add more text fields to this method. Presently I have to set up each text box with two buttons to enable save and load of the string and im sure this cant be right as i have about 5 text fields.  Ive tried adding other textfields.text to the NSSstring but just keep getting errors

Comment: Could you post the errors you've gotten and the strategies you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give each of your textfields a unqie tag number, and then create a switch that deals with each textfield.

so something like:

```
 switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 1:
    [defaults setObject:savecontents forKey:@"savecontents2"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    case 2:
    //...
    case 3:
    //...
    case 4:
    case 5:
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Ive tagged my text fields, where does the code go? Under my my IBAction, whats the sender tag? is that what ive named my IBAction?

Comment: Yes, it should go under your IBAction. the command [sender tag] will get the tag of the element that initiated your IBAction